# View Controller doesn't get presented immediately

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, didselectrowatindexpath

In my social app, I have the "Home" screen, where there is a tableView, which contains up to 3 different cells! Then I implement the didSelect data source method, where I perform some comparisons to determine what kind of cell I just selected... (3 or 4 comparisons each time) For every cell I select, a new view Controller gets instantiated.. One for photo presentation, another one for a custom camera presentation and lastly, for another simple View Controller presentation...

The thing is, for an unexplained reason, if I press the iPhone home button and then open my app again and go and select one of those cells, it takes up to 7 seconds till it presents the view Controller! Then, if I dismiss that view Controller, go back to "Home" and select another cell, everything's ok!

Does anyone have any idea for what might be happening?

**Edit:**

```
if currentArea != "Somewhere" {
        if gettingContent == false && objectsArray.count == 0 {
            if firstOfLocalLeaderboard != nil {
                if indexPath.row == 0 {
                    let vc = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "TopTenAreaController") as! TopTenAreaController
                    vc.area = currentArea

                    let navVC = UINavigationController()
                    navVC.viewControllers = [vc]

                    self.present(navVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
                }
                else if indexPath.row == 1 {
                    if localLeaderboard.count > 0 {
                        let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "PhotoViewController") as! PhotoViewController

                        vc.objectsArray = localLeaderboard
                        vc.currentArea = currentArea

                        let navVC = UINavigationController()
                        navVC.viewControllers = [vc]

                        self.present(navVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
                    }
                    else {
                        let vc = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "CameraViewController") as! CameraViewController
                        vc.appearedFromHome = true

                        let navVC = UINavigationController()
                        navVC.viewControllers = [vc]

                        self.present(navVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
                    }
                }
            }
            else {
                if indexPath.row == 0 {
                    if localLeaderboard.count > 0 {
                        let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "PhotoViewController") as! PhotoViewController

                        vc.objectsArray = localLeaderboard
                        vc.currentArea = currentArea

                        let navVC = UINavigationController()
                        navVC.viewControllers = [vc]

                        self.present(navVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
                    }
                    else {
                        let vc = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "CameraViewController") as! CameraViewController
                        vc.appearedFromHome = true

                        let navVC = UINavigationController()
                        navVC.viewControllers = [vc]

                        self.present(navVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Can you please post some code to show the relevant `didSelectRow` method and also your `prepareForSegue`.

Comment: Are you doing something in a background thread?

Comment: @Rikh See updated code

Comment: @Honey Nope....

Comment: Are you doing anything in your `viewDidAppear` or `viewWillAppear` that maybe taking up quite a lot of time? Also put a break point at your relevant `self.present` line and check if the present statement is executed immediately or after a 7 second delay? And does it happen for **all** navigation controllers or just one?

Comment: I'm confused even though you weren't doing anything in a background thread, the `DispatchQueue.main.async` solved your problem?

Comment: @Honey Exactly.. I'm using the Parse SDK which does things in the background, but I'm not calling any of its methods in didSelect method...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    // present vc
}
```

Comment: Could you please explain why?

Comment: he isn't doing anything in the background...so he is already on the main thread...

Comment: @shallowThought - UI updates must happen on main thread, and if you don't, you can see curious delays. So Nikita is guessing that if you're seeing strange delays, that you're doing something from a background thread. If that's true, then dispatching it to the main thread, it can solve it (if that is, indeed, the problem). Personally, rather than sprinkling the code with dispatches to the main thread, I'd probably insert preconditions (e.g. `dispatchPrecondition(condition: .onQueue(.main))`) and see if I can confirm Nikita's thesis, and slow back track to figure out how that's happening.

Comment: Frankly, while Nikita's prescription fits one possible source of these symptoms, I am skeptical with the diagnosis. Like Honey, I'd need to see some evidence that you're doing stuff on a background thread before jumping to this conclusion.

Comment: Inside didSelect, I'm not doing anything in the background.. I've posted part of the code above...

Comment: It worked! I put the whole didSelect content in the async block and it works every time! What could be the issue?

Comment: @Rob If I'm understanding what * dispatchPrecondition* can do, its just a conditional thread switch as in if I'm on the main thread then it would proceed, if not, it would switch to main thread and proceed again. right? If that is the case why not just always just do `DispatchQueue.main.async`...

Comment: Correct, the `dispatchPrecondition` is just going to fail if it's not the main thread, helping us identify whether Nikita's presumption was correct or not. Only if this fails do we go about identifying how that's happening (as the code in your question should not be doing that. My point is that you shouldn't just sprinkle your code with dispatches to the main thread: That's only code smell for "I have no idea which thread this code is running on", which is usually symptomatic of deeper problems. You really should know what thread various routines are running on.

Comment: @Rob You mean just for validating the current thread we should : `if dispatchPrecondition(condition: .onQueue(.main))) {print("we are current thread and Nikita's assumption pecurly true"} else { print("his assumption isn't true")`

Comment: @Honey - No, it's more like an `assert` statement: If the precondition is satisfied, it will quietly continue execution. If it's not, though, it will crash. But if you're running this through the debugger, though, execution will stop right there and you can see which thread it was running on, the stack trace, etc., i.e. quite a few clues that will help you diagnose _why_ it wasn't on the main thread.

Comment: @Rob in general what could create such unexpected delays? Asynchronous tasks, timers, heavy tasks anything else? What are things I need to check?

Comment: First, check to see if it was running on a main queue or not. Then, we'll know whether we're looking for some other mysterious delay on the main thread or why it's mysteriously running on a background thread. Start narrowing it down.